# Azure Bulk API Call for Network Interface Card

Tags: azure, cloud, network-interface

I wanted to know if there is a way to do a bulk API call on the network interface cards (NICs) on Azure.

For example, if I have a 100 NICs, instead of having to update them one by one, is there a way to update all or some of them at the same time, like batch them together and then make a single API call to update them all?

Please let me know if someone is aware of this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do that, why you want to do via the way? Would you accept to use powershell to do that? just use a loop, even if it essentially calls several apis, but it is convenient.

Comment: Because like I mentioned I have around a 100 NICs. And I want to be able to do that via code and a single call is more time saving of course